# nginx auth TCP socket not http request?

Tags: http, authentication, nginx, tcp, request

It is possible with nginx to auth a request via backend service such as

```
location /somewhere_restricted {
    auth_request /isallowed;
}
location = /isallowed {
    proxy_pass backend_auth
}
```

However the backend_auth is check at each http request. Is it possible to authorize a TCP socket? The socket will be authorized once and then all http requests made through it would be going through. Noting I am using http2

This is what is happening with websocket for instance, but I would need the same functionality for normal http requests, and I could not find anything related to this yet

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an authorized TCP socket. Authorization is part of the application protocol and a generic TCP socket has no specific application protocol. Also the `location` is specific to the HTTP protocol, i.e. generic TCP has no location.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was hoping of a way to mark the TCP connection like it is done with iptables for instance, so that once the connection is marked then can let it through. I am using websocket and nodejs wich makes it easy to authorise a (web)socket and then send files through it, but was hoping to be able to do similar thing directly with nginx and not having to use custom protocols then on a websocket